# Is there an equivalent "why-upgrade PostgreSQL" tool for PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, maintenance

I rarely keep up with the PostgreSQL and PostGIS releases and it can a challenge deciding on when to do so for the major/minor releases.  The why-upgrade site (http://why-upgrade.depesz.com/show?from=9.5.1&to=9.6.7) helps show what I am missing or risking by not upgrading.

Is there an equivalent site for the PostGIS extension?

Comment: Well, the low-tech version is the `NEWS` file: https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/browser/branches/2.4/NEWS